# How to write plugins for a production RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I want to write a plugin for an existing, production RCP application. As it is in production, I don't have access to the source or project files. However it has clearly defined plugins with plenty of extension points.

I've been reading tutorials on RCP development but most of these work with sample projects. How do I set-up an eclipse project so that I can contribute to this applications extension points?

Comment: Create an RCP target platform from its plugin set.

Comment: That was easy ... thanks man